# How to mock response.readEnity(String.class), passing mock Response object

Tags: rest, mocking, mockito, junit5

I want to mock response with payload as a simple string.
Below code is in my test :

```
Response response = mock(Response.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(mockRestClient.get("someMockUrl")).thenReturn(response);
when(response.readEntity(String.class)).thenReturn("XXXYYYZZZ");
```

Also tried with:

```
Response response  = Response.status(Status.OK).entity("XXXYYYZZZ").build();
```

MyCode looks something like this :

```
Response response = restClient.get(tokenUrl); // I was mocking this and getting mock response
String requestToken = response.readEntity(String.class); //failing at this line
```

None of the above is working.
Help is Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the issue was with using the deep stubs. It was not necessary in my case.

```
Response mockResponse = mock(Response.class);
when(mockResponse.readEntity(String.class)).thenReturn("XXXYYYZZZ");
```